# Raspberry Pi and GitLab

Tags: git, raspberry-pi, gitlab, raspbian

Is there a way I can run GitLab (http://gitlab.org/gitlab-ce) and GitLab CI (http://gitlab.org/gitlab-ci) on a Raspberry Pi device running Raspbian?

I want to have my own internal Git box where I can store code and possibly allow other friends access to upload their code too. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Official way for the Pi 2

There is a very easy way to install it on the Raspberry Pi 2.

```
wget https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/downloads-packages/raspberry-pi/gitlab_7.9.0-omnibus.pi-1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i gitlab_7.9.0-omnibus.pi-1_armhf.deb
```

You might prefer to go to [the official page](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/04/21/gitlab-on-raspberry-pi-2/) in order to get latest version. It's fast and easy, they recommend at least 1Gb swap.

On the Pi B and B+ you will hit the memory limit very soon and get degraded performance as you grow, but on the Pi 2 it works nicely, specially if you mount your repos on an external USB hard disk.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to install GitLab on the Raspberry Pi. You will need the Raspberry pi model B  reversion 2012 or model B+ (512mb of RAM). Installing GitLab takes a very long time.

Steps:

1. Get a fresh copy of the latest Raspbian and expand the file system. Be sure to boot to text mode.
2. Free-up space by typing: `sudo apt-get purge xorg lxde xinit openbox lightdm && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean`
3. Add some more swap space by typing: `sudo dd 
   if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile1 bs=1024 count=524288` (this will take a minute or so)
4. Activate the swap space by typing `sudo mkswap /swapfile1 && sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile1 && sudo swapon /swapfile1`
5. Get an external hard drive and format it as **ext4**. (very important)
6. Add the Git user: `sudo adduser --disabled-login --gecos 'GitLab' git`
7. Delete everything in /home/git `sudo rm -rf /home/git/* && sudo rm -rf /home/git/.*`
8. Add the following in /etc/fstab: (`sudo editor /etc/fstab`)

   `/swapfile1 none swap defaults 0 0
   /dev/sda1 /home/git ext4 defaults 0 0`
9. Reboot: `sudo reboot`
10. Follow the instructions here for the latest version of gitlab (currently 7.7): https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/7-7-stable/doc/install/installation.md

**Notes:** On step "Install Gems", when you type `sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test mysql aws`, It will take several hours, especially while fetching the gem sources and installing "kgio". You can ignore all incompatibility messages during this process.

Another thing to note is that creating a project inside GitLab takes a very long time. Just return to the dashboard if it takes more than a minute.

Answer (score 4):

You can find [GitLab requirements](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/requirements.md) here. If you have Raspberry Pi model B (512MB of RAM), I think that you can run GitLab but you might encounter performance issue.

I'd suggest that you take [a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438163/web-interface-for-git-repositories) to find lighter systems.

Comment: I had a look at Gitorious as an alternative but I don't know whether the Pi can handle that either

Comment: Maybe use cgit (http://git.zx2c4.com/cgit/) which is a very fast and lightweight systemm

Answer (score 1):

I use Gitolite on a small server and it's pretty awesome.  There is no web UI.  Gitolite itself is just a git repo you push and pull changes to to control access

https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite

Answer (score 1):

On your expanded, up-to-date raspbian, edit the swap space config file:

```
sudo vi /etc/dphys-swapfile
```

Change CONF_SWAPSIZE from 100 to 1000

Follow the instructions for the latest GitLab, at the moment:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/8-14-stable/doc/install/installation.md

Happy gitting!

Comment: you may want to include why the user should increase the swapsize.

Answer (score 0):

For those still interested in running versioning systems (and more) on a Pi, I wrote an article of what I tested [here](http://thebugfreeblog.blogspot.com/2021/03/versioning-and-cicd-on-raspberry-pi-or.html). In my experience, recent versions of GitLab are very difficult to run on a Pi 2/3, but work well on Pi 4. For Pi versions < 4 I suggest [Gitea](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea), for Pi == 4, I suggest GitLab. In the article, I listed docker images that can be used to run both services in a few minutes:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/carlonluca/gitea
- https://hub.docker.com/r/carlonluca/gitlab

In the article there are also info on CI/CD with Jenkins and GitLab.