# Always gitlab 502 error on RaspberryPi

Tags: ruby, git, gitlab

I 'm despair. I am trying to install gitlab for 3 days without success on my RaspberryPi 2 with Debian. I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606735/raspberry-pi-and-gitlab) guide at the newest version of gitlab (7-8-stable). I also installed the newest ruby version 2.2.1. If I ran `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production` all field are green so the installation should be correct. [Here](http://pastebin.com/iZSgJHSk) is my `unicorn.stderr.log` file after the gitlab start an after the first site calling. The only error in the `production.log` file is

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  database "gitlabhq_production" already exists
: CREATE DATABASE "gitlabhq_production" ENCODING = 'unicode'
PG::Error: ERROR:  database "gitlabhq_production" already exists
: CREATE DATABASE "gitlabhq_production" ENCODING = 'unicode'
```

and makes no sense for me. [Here](http://pastebin.com/00v1aP6D) is the `sidekiq.log`file. I already set the timeout in the `unicorn.rb` file to 360.

A possible trouble could be the domain setting. I test gitlab in my local network so in every config I let the localhost option.

EDIT:

I test gitlab with a **static** local network ip `192.168.1.x`. Later I want to have access with the no-ip service and an domain like `xx.no-ip.org`. What should I write for

```
# Update GitLab config file, follow the directions at top of file
sudo -u git -H editor config/gitlab.yml
```

or in the nginx configuration. What is my fully qualified domain name?

I think the problem lies here:

```
E, [2015-03-08T12:36:19.560253 #2751] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 2779 SIGABRT (signal 6)> worker=2
I, [2015-03-08T12:36:19.583573 #2878]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready
```

but I don't know how I can fix the problem.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Finally I have it. [This](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8809) post was very helpful. Thanks for help! ... :/

Comment: Linking to a now dead post really hasn't helped

Comment: @H2ONOCK I'm very sorry that I don't check every day if the link in my answer I wrote 3 years ago is still reachable...

Comment: No need to apologise for that, maybe just write better answers that can be viewed in time to come rather than linking out? Thanks.